# Angular/RxJS: keep interval running even in case of an error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to call a REST-service every 10 seconds. The REST-client call is inside an angular-service (myservice, function foo).

```
 ngOnInit ()
 {
      interval (10000).pipe (startWith (0), mergeMap (obs =>
      this.myservice.foo ())).subscribe (resp =>
      {
        this.data = resp;
      },
      error =>
      {
        console.log ("error");
      }
      );
 }
```

That is working as long the connection to the REST-service is ok. But if I stop it, then the interval stops too.

What do I need to do to keep it running (and failing) even if the REST-service is off?

Comment: Could you put together a stackblitz? That way we can try out some error isolation techniques with this specific scenario to see what works before posting.

Comment: You can see a video about error isolation here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q--U25yPTrA&feature=youtu.be&t=1240

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about cathing the error on the "inner" observable (the one that may actually produce errors), not the whole stream? Something like:

```
ngOnInit () {
  interval(10000).pipe(
    startWith(0),
    mergeMap(obs => this.myservice.foo().pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return empty(); // or return of(error) and do sth about it in the subscribe body
      }),
    ),
  )).subscribe(resp => this.data = resp);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a specific answer to the specific scenario (I would want to have a stackblitz to try it out before attempting to post suggested code). But here is a screen shot from a video that discusses error isolation from the great Ward Bell.

[image]

Notice the "wrong way" and "right way" comments above the two segments of code.

You can find this part of the talk here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q--U25yPTrA&feature=youtu.be&t=1240

Answer (score 1):

`FlatMap` the value to an inner observable which handles the error. On the inner observable add a `catchError` handler to the pipe that handles the error silently with an `empty` observable. Example:

```js
interval(10000).pipe(
  flatMap(num => of(num).pipe(
    mergeMap(num => this.myservice.foo()),
    catchError((error) => {
      console.log ("error");
      return empty();
    })
  ))
).subscribe(resp => {
  console.log(resp)
});
```

## [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qy3mzp)

Comment: Will this continue the interval? I thought not? "If an error occurs, the upstream Observable is dead". See the above referenced link at 22:42.

Answer (score 1):

You can use retyWhen error operator

```
interval (10000)
  .pipe(
    startWith(0),
    switchMap (obs => this.myservice.foo()),
    retryWhen(error => {
      return error.flatMap((error: any) => {
          if(error.status  === 503) {
              return Observable.of(true);
          }
          return Observable.throw({error: 'No retry'});
      });
);
```